# REGEX in notepad++ to only show lines containing certain text?

Tags: regex

I have a huge text file that has so much unneeded text and I want to just filter out the bits of text that interest me. The format for what I want is in the example below:

```
{\"animal\":\"crocodile\",\"class\":\"reptilia\"}
```

There are hundreds of different animals and of course classes.

How can I use regex in notepad++ to show only these lines of text in the whole document?

Comment: Are you trying to match any line with animal and class ?

Comment: There is thousands of lines of text around the parts I want. I want to remove all other text from the document and ONLY show the lines which interest me, which is in the example above. 

Doesn't matter which animal or which class. I just want to see them all without all the other text... is it possible?

Comment: I am not sure whether I understood the question. In notepad++ there is an option in the find box "Find all in current document" which will show all matches in a separate window.

Comment: Else let me know if you are looking for help with regex

Comment: The find all in current document would be great except it cuts off at the end of with an elipsis at before the animal and class part... This document im working with has really really long lines of text... nottepad++ doesnt seem to be able to show that long line of text in a single line in the search results.

Comment: Can you add into your question a bit sample (10, 15 lines) of the file marking which lines should stay and the ones that should not please? So we can actually test our solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT after last comment, you can try

Find what

```
(\\"(animal|class)\\":\\".*?\\")?\K.*?(?=\\"(animal|class)\\":)
```

Replace with

```
\n
```

- Regular expression
- `.` matches newline

Replace all

EDIT added double backslash `\\` to match `\` in the document.

following regex

```
\\"(animal|class)\\"\s*:
```

will match any of `animal` or `class` between `"` followed by 0 or more spaces followed by `:`

Comment: Hi, this gave me an error saying "Find: Can't find the text ""(animal|class)"\s*:"

Comment: are the `\\` backslahes in the question, in the text ?

Comment: Yes. The example is exactly as it is in the document

Comment: Nahuel, this now works but am I missing something? All it does is find the words animal and class? I am trying to remove all the other text from the document so only the animal and class remain.

Comment: The new edit worked AMAZINGLY well. Thanks so much for your persistent help!